# Code::Blocks error .exe has stopped working

Tags: c, compiler-errors, codeblocks

Whenever I am trying to run my code, a pop-up is coming saying program.exe  has stopped working.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char D[10];
    for(int i; D[i]!='\0';i++)
        scanf("%c",D);
    for(int i; D[i]!='\0';i++)
        printf("%c",D);

    return 0;
}
```

And here is one more which is causing the same error

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *ptr= (int*)1000;
    printf("%d %d ",ptr,*ptr);
    ptr=ptr+1;
    printf("New Value of ptr : %u",ptr);
    printf("%d %d ",ptr,*ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are probably different sources of errors in each code. This Code::Blocks error is very common.

Comment: Think about your codes again. The first is certainly wrong in so many ways.

Answer (score 0):

*Code::Blocks error .exe has stopped working* is a very generic error code with Code::Blocks. It can occur for many different reasons, so both cases have different bugs.

---

In the first one, `D` value is not set before being used in the `for` loop. The behaviour might be unpredictable when you will test `D[i] != '\0'`.

Then, you did not initialize `i` in your for loop. Do you mean

`for(i = 0; D[i] != '\0'; i++)` ?

The last `printf` is incorrect, you can't print a `char` array. Did you mean

`printf("%c", D[i]);` ?

---

I'm not sure about the second one, but I'm pretty sure the first line `int *ptr= (int*)1000;` is incorrect.
Try

```
int a = 1000;
int *ptr = &a;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first program, you haven't initialized i. You should put int i = 0 in the for loop.

Additionally, your program is an infinite loop. Because you are only scanning at D[0] every time. Are you sure you don't want to use a do...while loop?
You also don't need a second loop. You might want to see how to scan and print a string in c.

You may want to write:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char D[10];
    scanf(" %[^\n]s", D);
    printf("%s\n", D);

    return 0;
}
```

In second program use:

```
int a = 1000;
int *p = &a;
```

This ensures that the integer has its memory address reserved.